# Run Multiple Chromedriver sessions?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, watir

I am trying to run ten separate instances of Ruby's watir-webdriver using the chromedriver (to use Chrome). However they all seem to be fighting for port 9050 (the default port chromedriver runs on apparently). This causes an error message to appear in the output:

> Port already in use. Exiting.

The errors leave the browser open without any further script execution.

Can I run multiple instances of chromedriver, for example by running them on their own ports?

Comment: this doesn't even sound like the behaviour the ChromeDriver.  If you run just the exe itself, you can run several of it, and it always attempts to use a **random** port.  You must have some configuration making it try to use only a static port.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce the problem. Please make sure you have the latest [selenium-webdriver](https://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver) and [watir-webdriver](https://rubygems.org/gems/watir-webdriver) gems and [chromedriver](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list).

```
$ irb

> require "watir-webdriver"
=> true 

> chrome1 = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x..fe566050dd4713fcc url="about:blank" title="about:blank"> 

> chrome1.goto "google.com"
=> "http://www.google.hr/" 

> chrome2 = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x..fccc2afebe5385be4 url="about:blank" title="about:blank"> 

> chrome2.goto "yahoo.com"
=> "http://www.yahoo.com/"
```